# Creating xcode project dynamically

Tags: iphone, android

I have to create a web application where user can create thier own iphone and android app for book, they can give inputs for book icons, can upload file in epub, pdf , txt format. 
Can someone please suggest possible solution for how can I do it for iphone?

I have an idea of creating android project from command line and can also do the same from with in the application.

Answer (score 0):

How will you run the android app created by your web on android device?

Comment: i jus create a .apk file and download it or install it directly on my phone.